# たの at the end of 「そんなに寝ぼけるまで熟睡してたの？」

Tags: grammar, sentence-final-particles

Could you help me with this sentence (it's from Attack on Titan)

> そんなに寝ぼけるまで熟睡【じゅくすい】して**たの**？

そんな　refers to the muttering he did earlier

まで　probably doesn't mean "until", but rather "even"

So something like, "even half asleep, you do..."
I'm just not sure how the 熟睡 part fits in, and how the ”たの” works.

I appreciate any help on that matter.
Thanks :)

Comment: I translated 熟睡してたの? as "Were you sleeping deeply?".
And I translated そんなに寝ぼけるまで as "like you are still half asleep" but I am not sure.

Comment: Thank you everybody for the help. Now everything makes perfect sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The previous sentence is Eren saying なんで、ここに... which can be translated to "Why am I here?"

そんなに means "so", "so much". For the differences with こんなに and あんなに, see this : [Why use あんなに instead of こんなに when expressing one's memories?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11824/why-use-%E3%81%82%E3%82%93%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AB-instead-of-%E3%81%93%E3%82%93%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AB-when-expressing-ones-memories(refering)

まで in this case means "to such an extent".

ねぼける means "to be half asleep" or "to act strangely, to be disoriented, to be confused, to ramble, as if just waking up".

熟睡 means a deep sleep.

してた is a casual way of saying していた wich is just the past tense of the ている form of する.

の? is a feminin way of saying のか。/のだ? which here combines a bit of surprise and asking for explanation/confirmation about the situation you just saw/heard, in this case, Eren not knowing where he is.

So the whole sentence means : "You were sleeping deeply enough to be *that* confused?"

Comment: Ending a question with の isn't feminine: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11914/6840

Answer (score 2):

> 熟睡する　　 "enter deep sleep"
>   熟睡している "be deeply asleep"
>   熟睡していた "was deeply asleep"

+

> 寝ぼける　　　　　　 "become disoriented (due to sleep)"
>   そんなに寝ぼける　　 "become *that* disoriented"
>   そんなに寝ぼけるまで "until (you) become *that* disoriented"

=

> そんなに寝ぼけるまで熟睡していた　　 "(You) were so deeply asleep until you became *that* disoriented."

Then, turn it into a question with 「の？」:

> そんなに寝ぼけるまで熟睡していたの？ "(You) were so deeply asleep until you became *that* disoriented?"

And drop the 「い」 as is commonly done in colloquial speech:

> そんなに寝ぼけるまで熟睡してたの？ 　"(You) were so deeply asleep until you became *that* disoriented?"

And finally a slightly more natural translation:

> そんなに寝ぼけるまで熟睡してたの？ 　"You were sleeping so deeply that you became *that* disoriented?"

Answer (score 1):

As a native Japanese speaker, let me answer. I am really afraid to say, do not misunderstand the "structure" of my tongue, otherwise you will probably misunderstand forever.

First off, the sentence you made perfectly makes sense.

Now let me explain "linguistically"

”してたの” will be divided into, well, 4 pieces! ( What a complex language, my friend, but the
since the structure is completely different from English from the very basic, please hang on to it )

----> し/て/た/の。

First し is variable form of "old" word "す”, which according to the word that come after
it changed to "し”　( linguistically categorized as "conjunctive form" ( = in order to continue to next word て )) ---> in English, meaning "do"

Second "て” was actually, or historically, a verb, however, it lost the original meaning and
currently categorized as noun so that the sentence can be continued. ---> In English, meaning, nothing, just a "superficial" noun.

Third "た” means in English, "finish", being categorized as "auxiliary".

Finally, "の” is expressing the "question" in English, so to say, linguistically categorized as a particle.

Soooooooooo, after long jargon, "してたの”　means in English, "( you ) did so?"

Since Japanese is S-O-V, you have put in "熟睡” correctly. Because it is a noun = O.

I explained V in your sentence above.

熟睡＝O + してたの = V = "did you so?"

Wow, I think I am going nuts. ha-ha.

Comment: If you really wanted to break it down, that would be 5 pieces, even though there are only 4 kana;) た is a shortening of たり <- てあり, ie. it consists of the two verbs つ and あり. Not that it would help the question asker, just saying.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen 「て」 referred to as a noun... usually a 接続助詞?　Normally nouns don't connect to the 連用形 of 用言, so it seems like a strange categorization.

Comment: >> butorange, Yes, you are right. However, even though what you said is correct, "たり" is too old. Nobody uses it anymore other than some historical drama stuff.

>>Darius, I am sorry, you are right. てis接続助詞, = particle.

Answer (score 0):

The `してたの?` denotes both a question and a feeling of astonishment.

For example, the sentence translate to

`Did you have such a good sleep that you're only just half awake right now?`

Which poses a question of whether thr subject had a good sleep, and at the same time express doubt and astonishment that someone could be having a good sleep in that situation. (You know, with all the 巨人 around :/)

Comment: たの is not even a single unit, it's a misparse by the OP...

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Sorry if I confused you, but I am in no way suggesting that `たの` is a single unit. I've changed it to `してたの` so I hope that makes you feel better.